# How to reset py's database?

Tags: python, windows, scoop-installer

A vscode extension needs to use [`py`](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#launcher) launcher. I installed Python via [`scoop`](https://scoop.sh/) and it works:

```
PS C:\Users\W> python --version
Python 3.12.1
```

When checking for `py`, it is where it is expected to be:

```
PS C:\Users\W> Get-Command py

CommandType     Name                                               Version    Source
-----------     ----                                               -------    ------
Application     py.exe                                             3.12.1150… C:\Users\W\scoop\apps\python\current\py.exe
```

So far so good. Now when I actually want to launch `py` I get

```
PS C:\Users\W> py
Unable to create process using 'C:\Users\W\scoop\apps\python\3.11.3\python.exe': The system cannot find the file specified.
```

`py` seems to point to an old version that I may have had in the past.

I uninstalled Python, checked that `py` is now unknown, and reinstalled it afterwards. The effect is the same - this information must have been saved somewhere, and worse, this is the only Python installation `py` knows about:

```
PS C:\Users\W> py --list
 -V:3.11 *        Python 3.11 (64-bit)
```

`3.11` is nowhere to be found and `py.exe` directly comes from the `3.12` installation

```
PS C:\Users\W> ls C:\Users\W\scoop\apps\python

    Directory: C:\Users\W\scoop\apps\python

Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
d----          21/12/2023    17:35                3.12.1
l-r--          21/12/2023    17:35                current -> C:\Users\W\scoop\apps\python\3.12.1
```

I am now at the end of my journey to try to understand where th eproblem is, thus my question: **how to reset the `py` database of installed Python versions?**

Comment: According to the [PEP that specifies it](https://peps.python.org/pep-0397/), there should be a `py.ini` either in `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local` or at the location of the launcher executable (`py.exe`), which in my case sits in `c:\windows`. However, I don't have it there, only a `py.ini.template` -- I guess it just autodetects the available versions in my case.

Comment: @DanMašek: thanks for the tip. Unfortunately I do not have a `py.ini` anywhere on disk.

Answer (score 1):

I searched the Registry for `3.11.3`, found it at `HKEY_USERS\<my user UID>\Software\Python\PythonCore\3.11.3` and removed completely.

`py` then could not find any installation.

I then uninstalled/installed Python (via `scoop`) and still no available installation according to `py`.

The `scoop` install provides at the end a `.reg` file that populates the Registry path above (somehow it did not propose it with my previous installations).

Adding the Registry entry finally fixed the issue

```
PS C:\Users\W> py
Python 3.12.1 (tags/v3.12.1:2305ca5, Dec  7 2023, 22:03:25) [MSC v.1937 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

I belive that this issue will be specific to `scoop` installations, I will update the tags.